# VB.Net Show user form or trigger user form to show from non UI thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, forms

I have a bit of an issue and I've sort of backed myself into a corner with com objects and multithreading.  I need to display a user form, which as I understand it must be called from the UI thread, but I need to trigger this from the non UI thread and wait for the user to complete a task on the form before proceeding.

A little more detail:  I'm generating a collection of emails in Outlook in a seperate thread.  After the emails are created the user reviews copies of the mailitem.htmlbody properties for each message in a user form.  I've already worked out how to get the thread I'm processing the messages in to proceed, with a couple of boolean properties, but I still need to figure out how to display the user form.

I've tried

```
MessageReview.Show()
```

and

```
MessageReview.ShowDialog()
```

and

```
Dim reviewMessages As New Thread(Sub() MessageReview.Show())
reviewMessages.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
reviewMessages.Start()
```

Interestingly, the last of these fails silently.  No form displays, but there are no errors either.

EDIT:  I just tried this as well:

Set up delegate

```
Private Delegate Sub ClickReviewMessages()
'There is a button on the user form that let's you view this form as many times as needed

Private Sub ReviewMessagesClick()
    If ReviewButton.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim callback As New ClickReviewMessages(AddressOf ReviewMessagesClick)
        ReviewButton.Invoke(callback, New Object())
    Else
        ReviewButton.PerformClick()
    End If
End Sub
```

But I wound up getting a `Parameter count mismatch.` error.

I was also thinking of trying some delegate sub to tie it to a button on my form.  Haven't tried that just yet though.

EDIT:  I just wanted to add that the user form I'm trying to display contains a WebBrowser control... it appears to be an ActiveX control and might be why I'm getting all the fuss over the control not being instantiated in an STA.

Any ideas?

Comment: What about calling `ShowDialog` didn't work for you?

Comment: ShowDialog raised an error dealing with the message not being displayed in an STA, which lead to my most recent attempt at the bottom.

Comment: Wow... you guys have overwhelmed me with good suggestions!  I'm going to try a few things and select an answer and get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `MessageReview.Invoke(New Action(AddressOf MessageReview.ShowDialog))`

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `Invoke` "Executes the specified delegate on the thread that owns the control's underlying window handle".  You have to pass it a delegate, so that's where the built-in `Action` delegate with the pointer to the `ShowDialog` method comes in.

Comment: I was thinking of the delegate subs and invoke method and wondering if something would be possible there.  Would this block the thread from continuing until Message Review form is closed?

Comment: This raised an error unfortunately.  The error is "ActiveX control '####### ... ####' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.  My user form has the WebBrowser control on it, I believe this is the source of the issue.

Comment: I wound up using a variation of this... in my application I have a "Review Messages" button on the main form that displays the Review Form as well, the idea being that the user can review the messages multiple times.  I used `ReviewButton.Invoke(New Action(AddressOf ReviewButton.PerformClick))` and that got the desired results.  The methods I was using that failed silently seem to have something to do with that button being disabled until all the processes had completed.  I hadn't realized this, but I was trying to perform the click before enabling the button.

Answer (score 0):

You should capture the `SynchronizationContext` of your main UI thread, then call `.Send()` to synchronously run a delegate that calls `ShowDialog()` to display your form on the UI thread.

Creating multiple UI threads leads to a world of pain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Invoke()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) within a thread to do something in the GUI Thread:

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Dim result As String

    'this will block the thread until the Form MessageReview is closed/hidden
    Me.Invoke(Sub()
                  Using frm = New MessageReview
                      frm.ShowDialog()
                      result = frm.TextBox1.Text
                  End Using
              End Sub)

    'result now contains a value
End Sub
```

Where `Me` is in this case a Form. You could pass a reference to the Form (or any control) into your worker threads.